# Do IVs affect heroes' maximum stats?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

Online [guides](https://rankedboost.com/fire-emblem-heroes/growth-rates-iv/) state that IVs impact your chance to gain stats on level up. That is, each character has a range of IVs which impact their chances of rolling well when leveling up.

Stats can also be increased by merging characters.

Does this mean that the advantage of high-IV characters can be overcome by merging lower-IV characters? This would imply that all versions of the same character have the same potential, just a different amount of effort to get there. Is this true?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think you're confusing Fire Emblem for Pokemon. The characters' stats in Fire Emblem are not determined at time of acquire like in Pokemon (hence the Individual Value of each 'mon). Instead, each stat is determined randomly upon level up. You can see this in practice if a character levels up, falls in battle and resets to where they were, then levels up in a later battle. The two level up events may or may not be the same.

Comment: @ dirty beach - edited to provide more clarity. Yes, I have noticed different amounts of stats if a character levels up, dies and levels up again. My understanding is that IVs make the character "more lucky" in their dice rolls, and that over the course of leveling up multiple times, will lead to high IV versions of a character having higher stats. If I am misunderstanding IVs, then any correct answer that points out how they actually work will be made the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the higher-IV character will be able to receive the same stat bonuses from merging, thus, two characters that have merged the maximum number of times (10) will have the same bonuses, with the higher-IV character having the same advantage as before. This is explained in [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/204447-fire-emblem-heroes/74969058):

> You can merge up to a maximum of "+10". At Lv40, each merge gives 2 stat points. At "+10", you always end up with 4 extra points in each of the 5 stats.